# Correlation between many variables in one column

Tags: r, correlation

I have data frame (df) with 2 columns e.g.

```
Variable(character):      Value(numeric):     
A                       12.25             
A                       2.14              
A                       31.10              
B                       4.6      
B                       6.987
D                       74.10
D                       6.17
D                       10.365
D                       54.98
C                       10.47
C                       156.1420
C                       1.69
```

I would like to calculate the correlation between each variable. Something like that (values are completely random:

```
      A        B          D        C            
A     0.25     0.32       0.1256   0.9               
B     0.9      0.47       0.125    0.144
D     0.36     0.12       0.87     0.54          
C     0.369    0.147      0.4      0.485
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your variables have all the same number of observations:

```
cor(as.data.frame(split(df$val, df$var)))
```

Produces:

```
           a          b          c          d
a  1.0000000  0.3332724 -0.4755813 -0.1367066
b  0.3332724  1.0000000 -0.9171748 -0.2348487
c -0.4755813 -0.9171748  1.0000000  0.5713294
d -0.1367066 -0.2348487  0.5713294  1.0000000
```

The assumption doesn't hold true in your data.  Not sure how you intend to calculate correlations with unequal number of observations.  Here is the data I used:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(var=rep(letters[1:4], each=4), val=runif(16))
```

Comment: It's true my data doesn't have the same number of observations (hydrological measurement data). Any idea, how to deal with that?

Comment: @amikoma, are they time series data?  Then the right thing to do would be to align them all on the same time series filling in the missing values with NAs.  You tell me, how do you expect A (3 obs) and B (2 obs) to be compared?  Do you know something about A that tells you which (if any) of the observations should be compared to B?